# How to add RootNamespace attribute to project without assemblyinfo.cs to fix localization?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-sdk

I have an asp.net core project with the following properties:

- filename: WebApi.csproj
- Rootnamespace: Cmp.WebApi.csproj
- AssemblyName: (not set)

I'm trying to use asp.net localization, but the resourcemanager cannot locate the language resources.
The docs provide some answer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rootnamespaceattribute

> If the root namespace of an assembly is different than the assembly name:
>
> - Localization does not work by default.
> - Localization fails due to the way resources are searched for within the assembly. RootNamespace is a build-time value which is not available to the executing process.
>   If the RootNamespace is different from the AssemblyName, include the following in AssemblyInfo.cs (with parameter values replaced with the actual values):
>
> ```cs
> using System.Reflection;
> using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
>
> [assembly: ResourceLocation("Resource Folder Name")]
> [assembly: RootNamespace("App Root Namespace")]
> ```

The problem is that in .net core 5 there is no longer an assemblyInfo.cs file but its being autogenerated. This means i'd need to add `RootNamespace` to the .csproj file somehow.

How can i do this?

**EDIT**
I've tried adding:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyMetadata Include="ResourceLocation" Value="Resources" />
        <AssemblyMetadata Include="RootNamespace" Value="Cmp.WebApi" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

To the .csproj file but that did not work - it generated the following assemblyInfo in obj

```cs
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadata("ResourceLocation", "Resources")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyMetadata("RootNamespace", "OPG.WebApi")]
```

Also note that this works fine if the RootNameSpace is the same as the assemblyname.

**EDIT 2**

I've also tried:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AssemblyResourceLocation>Resources</AssemblyResourceLocation>
        <AssemblyRootNamespace>Cmp.WebApi</AssemblyRootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

But that did not work aswell, which seems logical considering that i don't see those properties in the msbuild task:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/targets/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (and the only i found) is to add a rather empty `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

```cs
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

// In SDK-style projects such as this one, several assembly attributes that were historically
// defined in this file are now automatically added during build and populated with
// values defined in project properties. For details of which attributes are included
// and how to customise this process see: https://aka.ms/assembly-info-properties


// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible to COM
// components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from COM, set the ComVisible
// attribute to true on that type.

[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM.

[assembly: Guid("677ac300-e567-46dd-9281-cafe8d644224")]

[assembly: ResourceLocation("Resources")]
[assembly: RootNamespace("Cmp.WebApi")]
```

Which you can simply do by selecting the `properties` folder, right clicking to open the context menu and then choose `add > new item...`, and then choosing the AssemblyInfo.cs template:

[image]

This was in a asp.net core 5 project.